# Wait on SweetAlert response

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I currently have a function that asks the user for confirmation when changing a value in a dropdown. This works fine using the standard `JavaScript` `confirm()`. Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1gwLggfm/).

```
var prev_val;
$('#dropdownId').focus(function () {
    prev_val = $(this).val();
}).change(function () {
    $(this).blur();
    var success = confirm('Are you sure you want to change the Dropdown?');
    if (success) {
        // Proceed as normal.
    } else {
        // Reset the value & stop normal event
        $(this).val(prev_val);
        return false;
    }
});
```

But when using [`SweetAlert`](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/), the change event always takes place before I'm able to confirm/cancel. Meaning, when I select a new value, and pressing "cancel", it does not stop the event and reset the previous value. Which it does with the regular `JavaScript` `confirm` dialog.

```
var prev_val;
$('#' + dropdownId).focus(function () {
    prev_val = $(this).val();
}).change(function (e) {
    $(this).blur();
    return swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Do you want to change the dropdown?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        closeOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnCancel: true
    },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return true;
                } else {
                    $(this).val(prev_val);
                    return false;
                }
            });
});
```

It might also be interesting to note that this `JavaScript` might even be invalid (pretty new to `JavaScript`), e.g. returning from the `confirm` function and from the `swal` function not functioning.

However, after Googling around, I found people with similar issues.

- [how-to-use-confirm-using-sweet-alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31136889/how-to-use-confirm-using-sweet-alert)
- [how-to-run-a-sweetalert-instead-of-default-javascript-confirm-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430930/how-to-run-a-sweetalert-instead-of-default-javascript-confirm-method)

But that seems a bit hacky since it's preventing any action, but when selecting confirm he re-creates the function that should have been called by default. Which seems like quite a hack for something so simple.

Any possibility of the `SweetAlert` just acting like a regular `confirm` dialog?

Comment: Isn't your code working?

Comment: @rishabhdev It does for a regular JavaScript `Confirm`. But that's pretty bland, I'd like to use the SweetAlert dialogs to do the same thing.

Comment: Even the sweetAlert code seems correct. Whats the issue you are having?

Comment: @rishabhdev With the current code, I get a `SweetAlert` dialog, but it ALWAYS changes the value. Regardless of pressing `cancel` or `confirm` buttons in the dialog. I want it to stop the change event, just like with the regular `confirm` dialog

Comment: if possible than please provide jsfiddle of your code which you have done  with Sweet Alert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value does not get set back because `this` in `swal` is not the select, but the sweet alert dialog. So in your change event you have to define a variable that holds the changed select element and use it to set the value back when the user clicks 'No'.

```
.change(function(e) {
    var select = this; // save select element to variable

    $(this).blur();
    return swal({
        title: "Are you sure?",
        text: "Do you want to change the dropdown?",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        closeOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnCancel: true
    },
    function(isConfirm) {
        if (isConfirm) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return true;
        } else {
            $(select).val(prev_val); // use select reference to reset value
           return false;
        }
    });
});
```

You can find a working example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/frncsdrk/dq0agwzp/2/).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var prev_val;
$('#' + dropdownId).focus(function() {
  prev_val = $(this).val();
}).change(function(e) {
  $(this).blur();
  var self = this;
  return swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "Do you want to change the dropdown?",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
      confirmButtonText: "Yes",
      cancelButtonText: "No",
      closeOnConfirm: true,
      closeOnCancel: true
    },
    function(isConfirm) {
      if (isConfirm) {

        // preventDefault is useless since change event has already happened 
        // if Confirm is true then do nothing else
        // change with prev val
        //e.preventDefault();
        return true;
      } else {

        // this here does not refer the dom element
        // it might be changed because it is called through the swal library code at a later time, use self which is declared out of the callback context.
        $(self).val(prev_val);
        return false;
      }
    });
});
```